# Plot legend continuously updating for spectrometer

Tags: python, plot, legend

I'm currently running into some issues regarding how to continuously update a legend on a spectral plot.

Briefly, I'm collecting data from a spectrometer through pyseabreeze, and am using the function scipy.find_peaks() to find wavelength peaks within the spectrum.  The position(s) returned from this function directly correspond to the peak wavelength detected by the spectrometer (thus, in pyseabreeze, calling spec.wavelengths(peaks[i]) will tell me the ith peak wavelength in that spectrum).  I would like to have my plot legend continuously update with these peak wavelength values.  The light source I'm using can have an arbitrary number of wavelengths emitted, so I can add more peaks, or remove peaks, and the legend should update accordingly.

I've tried a few different iterations, and the closest I've gotten is below:
I can get just the wavelength values shown in the legend, but they don't update when I change the data (by changing the wavelengths).  You can see the labels don't match the peak values on the graph.
[Spectrum with legend not updating peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVMkO.png):

I'm able to properly update the graph data, and I don't change the size of the data being graphed.  I believe my issue has to do with the line1.set_ydata(), or the initial plotting above the while loop.  I've read about legend artists, but I'm quite unfamiliar with coding myself. Putting the label data in other locations does cause issues with the canvas not properly clearing (if I change wavelengths, the old curves still remain on the plot)

There is an external trigger for the spectrometer that constantly pulses, and is configured correctly.

I would like the legend to be updated every time the plot updates, and the format to be in a vertical list written as: "Wavelength x =   460.102nm
Wavelength x+1 = 501.203nm..."

I've attached the relevant code below.  Everything above is just spectrometer initialization and COM port parameters for the trigger

```
Wavelengths = spec.wavelengths()
Intensities = spec.intensities(1)
EndTime = time.time()+60*120
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
peaks,_ = find_peaks(Intensities,height = 1200) #Used to find peaks for multiple wavelengths          
for i in range(len(peaks)):
    if len(peaks) ==0:
        continue
    WavelengthLegend.append(round(Wavelengths[peaks[i]],3))
    LambdaLabels = WavelengthLegend[i]
line1, = ax.plot(Wavelengths,Intensities,'-r',label= str(WavelengthLegend))
plt.draw()

while time.time() < EndTime:
         SpecCamTrigger.rts = 1                 #Trigger camera & spectrometer
         Intensities = spec.intensities(1)
         peaks,_ = find_peaks(Intensities,height = 1200)         
         line1.set_ydata(Intensities)
         print("Peak values", Wavelengths[peaks])
         time.sleep(.3)
         SpecCamTrigger.rts = 0
         for i in range(len(peaks)):
             WavelengthLegend.append(round(Wavelengths[peaks[i]],3))
             LambdaLabels = WavelengthLegend[i]
         fig.canvas.draw()
         ax.legend() 
         plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)", fontsize=12)
         plt.ylabel("Intensity (counts)", fontsize = 12)
         plt.axis([400,700,0,16000])
         plt.pause(.9)
         fig.canvas.flush_events()
         WavelengthLegend.clear()


plt.close(fig)
spec.close()
print("-----Pulsing end-------")
LaserTrigger.rts = 0
```

I've tried changing the label location for the legend in various positions, and the plot either fails to update properly, or gives me errors about legend artists.